# Update Facebook Open Graph with app access token instead of user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to force facebook to update the OG information automatically using javascript (i.e. what you can manually do on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)), using an [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens).

I've been able to make it work using a [user access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens) and the api with the [following code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects):

```
FB.api("/", "post", {
    accessToken,
    id: url,
    scrape: true
  }, function(response) {
    console.log("Response", response)
  }
);
```

However when I try to use the app access token I get the error

```
"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.",
"type":"OAuthException",
"code":104"
```

I've tried obtaining the access token both using a `GET` request:

```
GET /oauth/access_token
?client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and by [concatenating the add id and secret](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

The result is the same when using `curl` instead of the Javascript api.

It seems to me it can't be intended that you can force an OG scrape as a user but not with an app token; it doesn't sound like a user oriented action.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you passing the API base address to FB.api? That is not how you use that method, it takes relative paths.

Comment: You're right it also works with the path `"/"`, I'll edit. However it still has the same problem with the app access token.

Comment: You are missing the parameter name. And btw., the app access token should never be exposed in publicly reachable client-side code.

Comment: True I should probably do it on the back end, but the problem remains (I tested with curl as well). By parameter name missing you mean I need `accessToken: accessToken'? If so it's unnecessary because I use ES6.

Comment: No, the API expects the token under the name `access_token`.

Comment: I tried, same result.

Comment: It definitively works with an app token, just tested that in Graph API Explorer.